# Using Linq to check if generic list in Dictionary contains a value

Tags: linq, dictionary, foreach, generic-list

How do I check if a dictionary already contains a set of coordinates?  I am using SelectManager and Where but the count is still wrong.  I don't think its checked the values in the the generic list.

I want it to iterate through the matchTile and check every other elements in the generic list for a condition (not part of question).

If it meets that condition, it get adds it to the same group.  When the next iteration comes, it should check if that element has already been added to a group.  If yes, it skips it.  If not, it creates a new group (List).

Can anyone help?

```
private void groupMatches(List<int[]> matchTile){
    Dictionary<int, List<int[]>> groups = new Dictionary<int, List<int[]>>();
    int i = 0;

    foreach(int[] coord in matchTile){
        var alreadyCounted = groups.SelectMany(x => x.Value).Where(x => x[0] == coord[0] && x[1] == coord[1]);

        Debug.Log ("counted: " + alreadyCounted.Count ());

        if(alreadyCounted.Count() > 0) continue;

        // Create new group
        groups.Add(i, new List<int[]>());   
        groups[i].Add(coord);

        foreach(int[] nextCoord in matchTile){
            if (...)
            {
                groups[i].Add(nextCoord);   
            }
        }

        i++;
    }   

    Debug.Log ("groups: " + groups.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try next code:

```
private void groupMatches(List<int[]> matchTile)
{    
    Dictionary<int, List<int[]>> groups 
         = matchTile.GroupBy(line => new{x = line[0], y = line[1]})
                    .Select((grp, index) => new{index, grp})
                    .ToDictionary(info => info.index, info => info.grp.ToList());

    Debug.Log("groups: " + groups.Count);
}
```